# Typing a generic function load(key: string) with optional default argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a Javascript function `load(key, defaultValue)` which fetches a value from some storage.
If called with only the first argument, the function will return `undefined` if the key is not found in the storage. But if called with `defaultValue` it will always return a defined value.

I want to type such function in TS to get something like this:

```
const a: number | undefined = load("answer")
const b: number = load("answer", 27)
```

So I tried to write this:

```
interface LoadType<T> {
    (name: string): T | undefined
    (name: string, defaultValue: T): T
}

const load: LoadType<number> = (name: string, defaultValue?: number): number | undefined => {
    if (name === "answer") return 42
    return defaultValue
}
```

But I get an error in the `load` assignement: **Type '(name: string, defaultValue: number | undefined) => number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LoadType'**

What I am doing wrong? Is what I seek even feasible?

---

I have tried to put the generic on the function signature instead of the interface (as suggested by **kelly**), like this:

```
interface LoadType {
    <T>(name: string): T | undefined
    <T>(name: string, defaultValue: T): T
}

const load: LoadType = (name: string, defaultValue?: number): number | undefined => {
    if (name === "answer") return 42
    return defaultValue
}
```

The compiler do not complain anymore, that's an improvement.
But then, I get an unknown type when I call `load("answer")` which prevents me from writing such code like `load("answer") ?? 42`.

Comment: Put the generic on the function signatures, not the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload a function to achieve what you want like this:

```
function load<T>(name: string): T | undefined;
function load<T>(name: string, defaultValue: T): T;
function load<T>(name: string, defaultValue?: T): T | undefined {
  // Implementation goes here
}
```

Note that overloading functions in typescript is a bit different from what you might be used to from other languages. In typescript, you define every possible callable signature (in your case the one with and the one without `defaultParameter`) and then you define an implementing signature. The implementing signature needs to combine all the callable signatures and provide one implementation for all of them.

That also comes with the downside, that inside your function you could return `undefined` despite the caller passing a `defaultValue`. But if you're aware of this and take care about what you return in which case, you can use this to achive what you want.

Comment: Isn't my `interface LoadType` equivalent to a function overload?
In any case, I need to have a type. Is there another way to get the corresponding type from this function overload?

Comment: Yes, in the updated question your interface is probably equivalent to an overload. You can explicitly specify the type of `T` when calling `load` like this: `load<SomeType>('answer');`. Is that what you are looking for? To infer the type from the usage, the parameter would need to have anything to do with the generic `T`. As it's just a `string`, the compiler is not able to automatically infer the return type, because it could really be anything.